# What can I do if afterAll is not being executed when a scenario fail?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, cucumber, hook, bdd

I have several scenarios to be executed. I introduce some test data in the database  (using beforeAll) before executing these scenarios and remove such data after executing the scenarios.

The problem is that if a scenario fails, the code present within afterAll is not being executed. Therefore, test data is not removed from the data base. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, You should mock the database connection, there are many libraries to do so, for instance if you are using `mongodb` have a look at [Mockgoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockgoose)

> Mockgoose provides test database by spinning up mongod on the back when mongoose.connect call is made. By default it is using in memory store which does not have persistence.

For the `afterAll` hook that never runs (Which is the default behavior in case a test fails):

I suggest you truncate everything in the `beforeAll` hook, so whenever you start running the tests you have an empty database, even if you have some data from the last run (which will not be the case if you use Mockgoose or similar)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me because I'm using postgres database.

Comment: Are you doing Unit Testing or Integration Testing?

Comment: Integration testing